# ¿Cómo hacer para que dos "print" impriman en la misma línea?

Tags: python, print

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se impriman dos cosas en la misma línea?

Uso

```
print("BMI:")
print (BMI)
```

pero me lo pone en diferentes líneas

Comment: Hola. Escribir en un fichero o en pantalla?

Comment: Me gustaría que aclararas la pregunta puesto que estamos aportando diferentes soluciones al problema con interpretaciones distintas. ¿Quieres imprimir en pantalla en una sola linea pero tener dos `print` en tu código? ¿Quieres simplemente imprimir en una sola linea y piensas que un `print` después de otro imprime seguido? ¿Quieres que tu `print` no salte de linea para que el siguiente imprima seguido?

Comment: Yo no termino de entender que buscas, aparentemente la salida debe ser algo como ``BMI: 444`` si  es eso basta con un print: `print("BMI:", BMI)` o formatear: `print(f"BMI: {BMI}")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar el [parámetro `end` de `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), que por defecto es `\n` (nueva línea). Si lo defines a cadena vacía o un espacio, ya lo tienes:

```
print("BMI:", end="")
print (BMI)
```

Por ejemplo yo lo probé con:

```
>>> if 1: 
        print("BMI:", end="") 
        print("bla") 
BMI:bla
```

Answer (score 2):

Este ejemplo te puede servir de ayuda:

```
import sys
import time

def restart_line():
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write('some data')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds...
restart_line()
sys.stdout.write('other different data')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

La función **restart line es la clave** ya que **permite situar al cursor en la linea anterior**.

Básicamente **lo que hace** es imprimir un string por consola y, pasados dos segundos, volver a escribir sobre la misma linea un string diferente.

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465348/how-can-i-print-over-the-current-line-in-a-command-line-application/465360#465360

**Por otro lado**, una solución para **evitar "machacar" lo impreso anteriormente** es la siguiente:

```
import sys
import time


bmi = 0

while(True):
    print("BMI: ", end="", flush=True)
    print(bmi, end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    bmi = bmi + 1
```

Espero que te sirva alguna de las dos soluciones,

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Usa la función `format` para incluir tantas variables como quieras.

```
print("BMI: {}".format(BMI))
```

o usa las nuevas *f-strings* en Python 3.6+

```
f'BMI: {BMI}'
```

Las f-strings sirven tanto para asignarlas a una variable...:

```
cadena_texto = f'Variable 1: {var1}, Variable 2: {var2}'
print(cadena_texto)
```

...como tambien para imprimir por consola:

```
print(f'Variable 1: {var1}, Variable 2: {var2}')
```

Puedes incluso alinear a dcha o a izda o definir un máximo de dígitos decimales, etc.

Mírate la documentación que viene explicado muy bien los diferentes usos. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Debes concatenar elementos haz `print("BMI:"+BMI);` lo mostrara en la misma línea.

Comment: No necesitas concatenar. Print admite varios parámetros y los muestra todos en la misma línea. Por tanto: `print("BMI:", BMI)`. Esto además funciona sin necesidad de que la variable `BMI` sea una cadena (la concatenación en cambio fallará en este caso)

Answer (score -1):

para sobrescribir en la misma línea se usa `print(texto, end='\r')`
por ejemplo si imprimo una lista de contenido variable sería
`print(*valores, end='\r')`
Intente:

```py
i = 0
while True:
 i = i + 1
 print("contador", end='\r')
```

Comment: El OP no quiere "sobreescribir", quiere "escribir a continuación".

Answer (score -1):

Podrias intentar ...
algo asi...
`

```
a="BMI:"
b="BMI"
print(a,b)
```

`
resultado

BMI: BMI

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: En realidad si pasas dos strings a la vez tampoco necesitas modificar el end, `print("foo:", "bar")` pintará `foo: bar` sin saltos de línea, y de hecho, añadiendo un espacio entre ambos strings. El argumento `end=""` solo es necesario cuando se invoca múltiples veces el `print()`, pues solo añade el `end` al terminar de imprimir todo lo que le pasas al método, tal como indica su nombre "end". Tal como está tu respuesta, generará un problema a la siguiente vez que se quiera imprimir, añadiéndolo a continuación de `BMI: BMI`...