# ¿Cómo realizo un contador progresivo estático en Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, contador

necesito realizar un contador en pantalla que me vaya mostrando la cantidad de casos que voy procesando con un script.

No quiero que sea línea por línea:

línea1 >>> 1

línea2 >>> 2

línea3 >>> 3

Y tampoco que imprima cada conteo en la misma línea con espacios:

línea 1 >>> 1  2  3

Necesito que quede estático en el shell, que permanezca fija la unidad, decena y centena:

línea 1 >>> 001

Sé que no imprimirá los dos ceros a la izquierda, pero es solo para explicar lo que necesito.

luego de diez conteos se verá sólo esto:

línea 1 >>> 010

La mejor referencia es como ver un reloj digital en pantalla, donde se puede ver cómo corren los segundos siempre en la misma posición.

Muchas gracias a cualquiera que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado? Sugiero leer [ask]

Comment: Hola fedorqui, en base a la sugerencia de lectura que me haces gracias. No encuentro en qué está mal mi pregunta, si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería. Evidentemente es complicado decir con palabras lo que estoy buscando. Ya he investigado en relación a un cronómetro pero trabaja en base a una función de tiempo. Por otra parte, todo lo que he encontrado está relacionado al uso de tkinter, que tampoco es lo busco.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer para que dos "print" impriman en la misma línea?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289034/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-para-que-dos-print-impriman-en-la-misma-l%c3%adnea)

Comment: No Triby, ese script imprime la secuencia que indico en el segundo caso: linea1>>> 1       2        3  pero no se borra el número previo. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Quiero que cuente del 1 al 3 (por ejemplo). Primero imprime 1, luego se borra el 1 de la pantalla y en su lugar se imprime el 2 y así sucesivamente. Cada número en el lugar del anterior.